# I can't Implement Custom Package

Tags: java, oop, package

I found **No package available erro**r in below program.if any one help me how can i sort this..

I have only one root directory name is **Collage** and they have 3 different classes **ME,IT,CE**

When I implement Me class then i got this error

**Code :**

```
import Collge.CE;

public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
 

        CE c1 =new CE();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a mistake in your import "Collge.CE;" should be "Collage.CE;"